# When I use savefig() in matplotlib the outcome is different from show(), how can I fix this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting with matplotlib using this code, ignore the names I did not have the energy to change them

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

daticap=np.genfromtxt("presa_dati_capello.txt")
capello=np.hsplit(daticap, 2)
xcap=np.concatenate(capello[0])
ycap=np.concatenate(capello[1])
smol=np.min(xcap)
bigg=np.max(xcap)

range=np.arange(smol,bigg,50)
plt.title("presa dati capello")
plt.xlabel("posizione [passi motore]")
plt.ylabel("intensità [ADU]")
plt.plot(370,15326,'ro')
plt.plot(450,17976,'ro')

plt.xticks(range, rotation=45)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.plot(xcap, ycap, 'b-')
plt.savefig('plot_presa_dati_capello', dpi=300)
```

the shown one is this (great, showstopping, incredible):

[image]

But the saved file is this one (why?):

[image: why]

It's somehow cut and I have no idea why I'm losing my mind.

I tried changing some things but I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: Try adding `plt.tight_layout()` right before `plt.savefig(...)`.

Comment: Are you running in Jupyter notebook with the default inline backend?  If so, try adding `bbox_inches='tight'` to your `savefig` call.  The inline backend automatically uses `bbox_inches='tight'`.

Comment: 'plt.tight_layout() ' worked, thanks!! should I like close the thread or something? @jared

Comment: @Dj003 Close it as duplicate.